# Is there any way to Run a Visual C++ project on a website

Tags: .net, visual-c++, web-hosting, execution

I want to create a website and run a Project created with Visual C++ 2008 Expression on it. 
I've read everywhere that its not possible to let an' exefile run directly on a website, but just to store it and to give the possibility to download it.

Now my question is: Is there any possibility to run a project built with Vc++ directly on a website, for example on one with Windows hosting:

http://hosting.aruba.it/hosting_con_spazio.asp?Lang=EN&offerta=1
?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible if your web host lets you run arbitrary executables as CGI scripts, which some of them do, but if you're not running it as a CGI script right now, it's highly unlikely it'll behave in the way you want.

Comment: What is an 'arbitary executable' and a 'CGI script', how can I find it out if the host lets it run like this and if it does, what do I have to do? (E.G. rename the exefile...).    Is a codesigning also helpful? The Windows hosting whit the .net platforms support, mentioned in the link of Aruba, is this a help? Does it change something?

Comment: Stackoverflow really isn't a tutorial site, if you don't know anything about web design, CGI, web servers, network programming, or web hosting, then there's a lot of homework you'll need to do by yourself before asking questions here will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I came across this some time ago. C++ rpc. If you store a `.exe` (for Windows) file in your `cgi-bin` directory, you can call it with PHP. This can be convenient for very heavy tasks. If I'm correct Facebook switched to C or C++ a few years ago.

Comment: Do You mean to store the file.exe created by the Vc++ project in my cgi - bin directory.    Excuse my ignorance, but where do I find this directory?

Comment: It's just a convention. You can call the file however you'd like. Most of the time it is stored in the root directory.

Comment: Ok, I've looked up rpc, cgi-bin and PHP on Google and now I've got at least a faint idea how to do it.   Now what I didn't get yet: the '.exe'  (for Windows) is the exefile built by the project? Now I have to put this exefile with the help of C++ rpc into the cgi-bin directory of the server. And this file I can call with PHP, right?  Are there any practical examples how to do that? I've never built a website, so its rather hard for me.

Comment: I could only guide you into the right direction by telling you that it is indeed possible and where to look, but I have ZERO experience with it. I would like to say though that if this is you first website, C++ might not be the right language. Even though I use it all the time for applications, a leak on a server can be disastrous. I advise you to only use it when performance is essential.

Comment: Yes, it is my first website and I know nothing about webdesign. Infact I thought to use the 'web builders', which allow You to build Your website quickly and without any knowledge of the appropriate codes.  Your advice is also valid for "Visual C++" (not to use it, if its possible?

Comment: Well, if you really are a beginner, it might be for the best to learn HTML and CSS (within a week), javascript (within 2 weeks) and PHP (within a month). These languages will teach you the essentials before you can start server side programming with C++. Check this website http://www.w3schools.com/ and http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11. Is there a reason why you'd like to use C++. If it is because you are familiar with it, than I have to say that programming with these languages will save you A LOT of time and effort. What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was writing a programm in Visual C++ for exercise only. Then I discovered that it could be useful if it ran directly in internet. The only reason, why I want to use Visual C++ is because the program is already written and it took me quite a long time. Though I'm totally ignorant regarding the web, I didn't know about the difficulties that I discovered, when the program was already written. Another reason is, that I have to put it in the web within a short time. This evening I'll phone a specialist who said he had an' idea how it could be possible and I'll comunicate his suggestion to You.

Comment: If he is a specialist, what he tells is a 1000 times more useful than what I can tell you. But I am interested in what he has to say. I encountered the same problem a few years ago and decided to let people download it. This was easier and avoided the need for expensive servers.

Comment: @ JMRC : Public servers usually don't allow any Exefiles, so its necessary to create an own server. Its enough to buy a used PC or notebook and install Windows Server 2003 or 2008 and connect it to a router. Then its necessary to get a static address. There are some who offer them gratis or at least at a low price. In the end its necessary to create a 'partition', what means, a part of the memory reserved for the users, because during the application of the exefile, the user needs also to write.  Windows/System administration/ Computer administration /Harddisk administration/Partition.

Comment: I think you're in for a long journey, but it probably will be a very a useful experience, good luck.